How to send large amount of products via WooCommerce Rest API
I am developing a plugin for WordPress. I am receiving products from a third-party API, but when I send requests to the WooCommerce REST API, I get an internal server error or a WooCommerce HTTP client error. Some products are imported, but then the import process stops in WooCommerce. The products can be imported completely if I manually restart the plugin each time.
I am using batch
What would be a solution for this?
$createChunks = array_chunk($creates, 90);
foreach ($createChunks as $chunk) {
$this->woocommerce->post('products/batch', ['create' => $chunk]);
sleep(2);

I am using batch, and timeout of 2seconds, increased memory size to 512M, and script execution time 3600.
Also I am using hetzner hosting.

I have suggest you can try by calling recurrence api with JavaScript > fetch.
Same functionality I have already used to generate full website cache in html. While it works fab. No server exhaust or never timeout for n number of requests 1 by 1.

You need to merge your logic into this.

function _buildCache(permalink, totalPost) {
  fetch(permalink + "?is_minify=1")
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        if (totalPost == -1) {
          location.reload();
        } else {
          cacheCount++;
        }
        if (totalPost == cacheCount) {
          //   COMPLTED HERE
          alert("Complted");
        }
        if (
          typeof allPostData !== "undefined" &&
          typeof allPostData[cacheCount] !== "undefined"
        ) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            _buildCache(allPostData[cacheCount].post, allPostData.length);
          }, 300);
        }
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to fetch:", response.statusText);
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Fetch error:", error);
    });
}

let allPostData = [
  "http://test.com/1",
  "http://test.com/2",
  "http://test.com/3",
];

_buildCache(allPostData[0], allPostData.length);

